# Understanding the proof of the concavity of entropy.

Tags: information-theory, entropy

[image: the proof of the concavity of entropy]

In the proof above it is hard for me to comprehend the equation, especially the $\log|X|$. What is the $u$, the so-called "the uniform distribution on $|X|$ outcomes"?

Any kind of suggestions for me to understand the equation or the theorem are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$u(x)=\frac{1}{|X|}, \forall x \in X$$

\begin{align}H(p)&=-\sum_{x \in X} p(x) \log p(x)
\\& = -\sum_{x \in X} p(x) \log u(x)-\sum_{x \in X} p(x) \log p(x)+\sum_{x \in X} p(x) \log u(x) \\ &
=-\sum_{x \in X} p(x) \log u(x) - D(p ||u)
\\ &=-\sum_{x \in X} p(x) \log \frac{1}{|X|} - D(p ||u) \\
\\ & = - \log \frac{1}{|X|} \sum_{x \in X} p(x)- D(p ||u) \\
\\ & =  \log(|X|) \sum_{x \in X} p(x)- D(p ||u) \\
\\ & =  \log(|X|) - D(p ||u) \\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed mathematical speculation. But could you please teach me any thing about the form of $\log(|X|)$? What is the relation between the cross entropy and that?

Comment: I know that it is for the proof, but any thing else, considering the saying of "uniform distribution on $|X|$ outcomes" Thanks.

Comment: I hope that you could provide me with any articles about this. $|X|$ and the "uniform distribution **on** its outcomes".

Comment: $\log (|X|)$ is a constant isn't it?

Comment: Let $X = \left\{1,2,3 \right\}$, $u_X(1)=u_X(2)=u_X(3)=\frac13$ which is a constant and $\log (|X|) =\log 3$.

Comment: $|X|$ is just the cardinality of the alphabet.  In example of coin tosses where you just care about head or tail, $|X|=2$. If you are interested in the outcome of a dice regardless of whether it is biased or not, $|X|=6$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks very much! Thus the uniform distribution is comprehensible.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh: Thanks, I have added your proof [here](https://statproofbook.github.io/P/ent-conc).